# Extended support for Ubuntu 12

Tags: 12.04, support

Not sure if there is a better communication mechanism for asking this question. Ubuntu 12 is EOL April 2017. Do corporations have any option to extend support on 12?

Thanks

Comment: There's a reason for EOL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will ESM also become available for Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1001714/will-esm-also-become-available-for-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is no.  They do not plan to support any release beyond the EOL.

More information can be found here:  https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life

Answer (score 2):

You should contact Canonical directly with your inquiry. While they do not advertise any support options beyond a version's official end-of-life date, it's always worth asking. Be sure to include the size of corporation (how many Ubuntu machines you need support for).

Canonical Support Sales:

sales@canonical.com

UK: +44 207 093 5161

USA: +1 781 761 9427

Comment: This doesn't extend time of support.  When the release goes EOL it gets no more support official or otherwise (no security updates, etc.)

Comment: @ThomasWard I understand that is Canonical's current, official position. That's not to say it would be completely impossible to work something out, especially for a large corporation willing to pay handsomely for custom, extended support. It's worth asking -- it's *guaranteed* to be an impossibility if you don't ask.

Answer (score 1):

Canonical announced that they will [offer Precise users extended "security patches only" support](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2017/03/14/introducing-ubuntu-12-04-esm-extended-security-maintenance/) contracts for customers under the Ubuntu Advantage support contract.

No word on how long will this plan be offered, but according to the press release - it is intended for customers "who have not yet had time to upgrade" to Trusty (3 years old now) or Xenial (1 year old now) - so anybody's guess is likely to be true, and if XP is to be assumed as the golden standard, then the answer is: for many years to come.