# Do I have to upgrade my Ubuntu 18.04 to higher version?

Tags: 18.04, server

We have been using Ubuntu 18.04 server for now and we are happy with it cause all our requirement meets in this version. Don't want to change this OS unless there is something which is important.

We have also plan to install Ubuntu 18.04 lately to other systems when its time comes as per our schedule which takes quiet some time. Will that be a problem even after Ubuntu 18.04 LTS support ends at the year 2023 ?

We have also tried upgrade to 19 earlier but few of our wanted requirements not works in updated version. So we stick with the 18.04. Please help us with some information.

Comment: you *could* consider [ESM](https://ubuntu.com/security/esm) to extend the life of security maintenance for version 18.04 beyond April 2023 for a further 5 years. Such an option will still place you outside of support on askubuntu

Comment: Ubuntu releases that are *year.month* in format are different products to those using the *year* format, and no *year* format releases exist for 2019 (ie. no Ubuntu Core 19).  Ubuntu *year* server products when upgraded do not need any application changes (different systems when compared to *year.month* format).  Your question though appears very *opinion* geared which is off-topic here (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and relates to details you've not provided (what applications you use, how you use the server etc) which may do better on a Forum rather than this Q&A site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will ESM also become available for Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1001714/will-esm-also-become-available-for-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 8):

> Do I have to upgrade my Ubuntu 18.04 to higher version?

No, unless

- you want support from this site.
- the system is exposed to the internet. Using internet on a system that does not get security updates should be a no-go for production systems. Risks needs to be avoided.

> Will that be a problem even after Ubuntu 18.04 LTS support ends at the year 2023

You can not update/upgrade 18.04 after support ends.

---

If you use an Intel or AMD 64 I would advice to start using virtual machines or containers until you fix your requirements.

Use the latest Ubuntu on all your systems, use VirtualBox and install 18.04 into VirtualBox (or create a VM from one of your systems and use that). Without connecting to the internet you will be fine using an older Ubuntu.

Comment: @ArturMeinild thanks and updated :)

Comment: Not to be picky, but presumably you mean - you can't download 18.04 from the *official* site after support ends. I've seen sites with 12.04 still available. I mean, if you really *want* it...

Comment: @JohnC you can even download it from the _official_ site for old releases: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/.